# Jquery functions does not work on dynamic generated form component?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using this jQuery function with *jQuery UI* to generate a *datepicker* when the user hits one textfield:

```
<script>
        $(function() {
        var dates = $( "#from, #to" ).datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
                var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                    instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
                    date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                        instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                        $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                        selectedDate, instance.settings );
                dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
            }
        });
    });
  </script>
```

As you can see it respond to the textfields *from* and *to*. The textfields are in my html code like:

```
<div class="clearfix">
            <label for="from">From</label>
            <input type="text" id="from" name="from" class="xlarge"/>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix">
            <label for="to">to</label>
```

At this point everything works. Later, in the same form a let the user to clone this form elements using this other code:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var removeButton = '<a href="#" id="remove">remove</a>';
        $('#addl').click(function() {
        $('div.jobitems:last').after($('div.jobitems:first').clone());
        $('div.jobitems:last').append(removeButton);
         $('div.jobitems:last input').each(function(){
           this.value = ''; 
        });

    });
    $('#remove').live('click', function() {
        $(this).closest('div.jobitems').remove();
    });
  });
                <input type="text" id="to" name="to" class="xlarge"/>
            </div>
```

When the user clone the elements, the new ones do not respond to the function that generates the datepicker. I'm really confused about this. **Here you can check the running code:** http://domingo.net46.net/example/reg.php

Comment: "You are seeing this page because the system administrator of 000webhost.com is currently checking this website for malicious content." Other than that ... Try running datepicker when you clone it.

Comment: well first thing is i'd change your method to look for a class. Cloning elements like above would result in items having the same ID not best practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call the function that make the datapicker happen again after the append of the html elements so that the datepicker work on them because i can see that the datepicker function is called on the document ready and you have another function that append html element so you have to call the datepicker function right after you append the html elemnt.

```
$(DoAction);

function DoAction() {
        var dates = $( "#from, #to" ).datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
                var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                    instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
                    date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                        instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                        $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                        selectedDate, instance.settings );
                dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
            }
        });
    }




$(document).ready(function() {
    var removeButton = '<a href="#" id="remove">remove</a>';
        $('#addl').click(function() {
        $('div.jobitems:last').after($('div.jobitems:first').clone());
        $('div.jobitems:last').append(removeButton);
         $('div.jobitems:last input').each(function(){
           this.value = ''; 
        });
            DoAction();

    });
    $('#remove').live('click', function() {
        $(this).closest('div.jobitems').remove();
    });
  });
```

Comment: can you give an example? Thanks!

Comment: It doest work, here is the complete html code: http://pastie.org/2466056 and here your JS code: http://pastie.org/2466059  Tell me what you think, if you need, i can give you access to my ftp server so you can test it. Thanks again for you help!

Comment: I am not a php expert so if possible, can you put a running code with the problem on jsfiddle.net it is a popular tool allow you to put ur html, js and css and test them and i will fix it for you. Or if you have a URL that contains a running sample i can see the case.

Comment: This is a very short version of the code in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/34xEg/ Tell me what you think, as you can see, the pickdate works only on the static elements

Comment: I debugged the ksfiddle and i found that the code the clones the div's that contains the data and append the code to the end is causing the problem..i tried to append a new control by hand, it worked fine. see http://jsfiddle.net/34xEg/1/ where i appended the new text by hand and it worked fine but it needs some updates but the datepicker is shown.

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be on the line that is as follows:

```
this.value = '';
```

Try changing this to become:

```
$(this).value = '';
```

Then it should work as it's creating a jQuery object

Answer (score -1):

If the cloned elements have the same `id` as the originals, I'm not surprised that the datepicker will only act on the first elements it finds.